# Trying to use here-strings in powershell 5.1 but not working

Tags: powershell

I'm getting red squiggles when I try to use here-strings in PS 5.1. What am I missing?

```
function Main {
    $csv = @"
    test1,test2
    "@

    echo $csv
}
Main
```

Error:

```
White space is not allowed before the string terminator.
```

Comment: The error is exactly the issue. You cannot have the pretty formatting when using a here-string.  Remove the tab before `"@` so that it has no whitespace before it on the line and the error should go away.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.3#here-strings "ends with a newline followed by the closing mark" meaning, no spaces are allowed between the newline and the closing mark

Comment: ok got it. however, if i put test1 and test2 on separate lines and try to use -split "," a blank lines appears between the 2 items. See updated in OP. I tried taking the comma out and splitting by ([Environment]::NewLine) but that didn't work either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note:

- The following applies up to at least PowerShell 7.3.2
- Improvements to the here-string syntax have been green-lit - both to support indentation and a *single*-line variant - but not yet implemented - see [GitHub issue #2337](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2337).

---

PowerShell's [here-strings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules#here-strings) have **strict syntax requirements with respect to the *closing* delimiter** (`'@` or `"@`):

- It must be **at the *very start of the line* - not even *whitespace* is allowed to precede it**.

This makes it tricky to use with *indented code*, because the indentation cannot be maintained, as you've experienced:

```
   @'
   hi there
'@  # OK: closing delimiter is at the *very start* of the line.


   @'
   hi there
   '@  # !! BROKEN -> error "White space is not allowed before the string terminator."
```

Additionally, note that **here-string *content* isn't indentation-aware either**:

- That is, the resulting verbatim value in the first example (the working one) is    `hi there`, i.e. *including* the leading whitespace.

Comment: Good point, @TheMadTechnician - that was ambiguous, and I took it out (I meant that it must be on a _new line_, after the string's _content_).